# Text-based Snake game on Window

Tags: c++, game, c++11, console, windows

How can I improve this game?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>

#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

using Matrix = std::vector<std::vector<int>>;
namespace
{
    HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
};

void clearScreen()
{
    static DWORD                count;
    static DWORD                cellCount;
    COORD                       homeCoords = { 0, 0 };

    if (!GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hStdOut, &csbi))
        std::cerr << "ERROR GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo - clearScreen : "
        << GetLastError() << std::endl;

    cellCount = csbi.dwSize.X *csbi.dwSize.Y;

    FillConsoleOutputCharacter(hStdOut, (TCHAR) ' ', cellCount, homeCoords, &count);

    FillConsoleOutputAttribute(hStdOut, csbi.wAttributes, cellCount, homeCoords, &count);

    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hStdOut, homeCoords);
}

namespace Tile
{
    enum
    {
        Empty,
        Wall,
        Food,
        Snake
    };
}

struct Point2D
{
    Point2D() = default;
    virtual ~Point2D() = default;
    Point2D(std::size_t row, std::size_t col)
    {
        this->row = row;
        this->col = col;
    }

    std::size_t row, col;
};

class NonCopyable
{
public:
    NonCopyable() = default;
    virtual ~NonCopyable() = default;

    NonCopyable(const NonCopyable &) = delete;
    NonCopyable(const NonCopyable &&) = delete;
    NonCopyable& operator = (const NonCopyable&) = delete;
};

template<typename T>
struct Random : public NonCopyable
{
    Random(float min, float max)
        : mUniformDistribution(min, max)
    {}

    T operator()()
    {
        return mUniformDistribution(mEngine);
    }

    std::default_random_engine mEngine{ std::random_device()() };

    template <typename U>
    static auto dist() -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<U>::value, std::uniform_int_distribution<U>>::type;

    template <typename U>
    static auto dist() -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<U>::value, std::uniform_real_distribution<U>>::type;

    decltype(dist<T>()) mUniformDistribution;
};

struct World : public NonCopyable
{
public:
    World() 
    {
        snake.emplace_back(Point2D(7, 7));
    }

    void performAI();

    bool moveSnake();

    std::size_t numberEatrn() const
    {
        return numEaten;
    }
private:
    Random<double> getRandom{ 0.0, 1.0 };

    bool randomChance(double time)
    {
        return getRandom() < time;
    }

    void placeFood();

    bool worldBoundry(const Point2D& pt) const;

    bool isCollide(const Point2D& head) const;

    Point2D getNextPosition(int dx, int dy);

    void draw(std::ostream& stream) const;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const World& self)
    {
        self.draw(stream);
        return stream;
    }

    Matrix mField
    {
        {
            { 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 },
            { 1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1 },
            { 1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1 },
            { 1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1 },
            { 1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1 },
            { 1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1 },
            { 1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1 },
            { 1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1 },
            { 1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1 },
            { 1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1 },
            { 1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1 },
            { 1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1 },
            { 1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1 },
            { 1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1 },
            { 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 }
        }
    };

    std::deque<Point2D> snake; 
    std::minstd_rand rndEngine;

    std::size_t numRows = 17, numCols = 15;
    int dx = 1, dy = 0; 
    std::size_t numEaten = 0;
    const double mTurnRate = 0.2;
};

void World::placeFood()
{
    std::size_t row = rndEngine() % numRows;
    std::size_t col = rndEngine() % numCols;

    if (mField[row][col] == Tile::Empty)
    {
        mField[row][col] = Tile::Food;
    }
}

void World::draw(std::ostream& stream) const
{
    clearScreen();

    for (auto&& i : mField)
    {
        for (auto&& j : i)
        {
            switch (j)
            {
            case Tile::Wall:
                stream << '#';
                break;
            case Tile::Food:
                stream << '$';
                break;
            case Tile::Snake:
                stream << '*';
                break;
            default:
                stream << ' ';
                break;
            }
        }
        stream << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << "Food eaten: " << numEaten << '\n';
}

bool World::worldBoundry(const Point2D& point) const
{
    return point.col < numCols - 1 && point.row < numRows - 1;
}

bool World::isCollide(const Point2D& head) const
{
    return !worldBoundry(std::move(head)) ||
        mField[head.row][head.col] == Tile::Snake ||
        mField[head.row][head.col] == Tile::Wall;
}

Point2D World::getNextPosition(int dx, int dy)
{
    Point2D nextSpot = snake.front();

    nextSpot.col += dx;
    nextSpot.row += dy;

    return nextSpot;
}

void World::performAI()
{
    Point2D nextSpot = getNextPosition(dx, dy);

    if (isCollide(nextSpot) || randomChance(mTurnRate))
    {
        int leftDx = -dy;
        int leftDy = dx;

        int rightDx = dy;
        int rightDy = -dx;

        bool canMoveLeft = !isCollide(getNextPosition(leftDx, leftDy));
        bool canMoveRight = !isCollide(getNextPosition(rightDx, rightDy));

        bool turnLeft = false;
        double timeToTurn = 0.5;

        if (!canMoveLeft && !canMoveRight)
        {
            return;
        }
        else if (canMoveLeft && !canMoveRight)
        {
            turnLeft = true;
        }
        else if (!canMoveLeft && canMoveRight)
        {
            turnLeft = false;
        }
        else
        {
            turnLeft = randomChance(timeToTurn);
        }

        dx = turnLeft ? leftDx : rightDx;
        dy = turnLeft ? leftDy : rightDy;
    }
}

bool World::moveSnake() 
{
    Point2D nextHead = getNextPosition(dx, dy);

    if (isCollide(nextHead))
    {
        return false;
    }

    bool isFood = (mField[nextHead.row][nextHead.col] == Tile::Food);

    mField[nextHead.row][nextHead.col] = Tile::Snake;

    snake.push_front(nextHead);

    if (isFood)
    {
        placeFood();
        ++numEaten;
    }
    else
    {
        mField[snake.back().row][snake.back().col] = Tile::Empty;
        snake.pop_back();
    }

    return true;
}

class Game : public NonCopyable
{
public:
    void run();

private:
    void displayResult();

    World mWorld;
    const double mWaitTime = 0.1;
    const size_t mMaxFood = 7;
};

void Game::displayResult()
{
    if (mWorld.numberEatrn() == mMaxFood)
    {
        std::cout << "Yay!  The snake won!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Oh no!  The snake crashed!\n";
    }
}

void Game::run()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    while (mWorld.numberEatrn() < mMaxFood)
    {
        auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        double timeTakenInSeconds = (end - start).count()
            * (static_cast<double>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::num)
            / std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::den);

        if (timeTakenInSeconds > mWaitTime)
        {
            mWorld.performAI();
            if (!mWorld.moveSnake())
            {
                break;
            }
            std::cout << mWorld;
            start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        }
    }

    displayResult();
}

int main() 
{
    Game game;
    game.run();
}
```

Comment: With this early checkmark, I assume these improvements were already enough to (assumably) post a better follow-up question.  I might look at more of the code later, but as I've mentioned, it will be easier to read as separate files.

Comment: @Jamal .. i think you are reading my mind :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestions:

**Change default constructor of `Point2D`**

When you use

```
Point2D() = default;
```

and a user construct an object using:

```
Point2D p;
```

the members `row` and `col` are uninitialized.

Change it to:

```
Point2D() : row(0), col(0) {}
```

**Initialize members in the initializer list**

Change

```
Point2D(std::size_t row, std::size_t col)
{
   this->row = row;
   this->col = col;
}
```

to

```
Point2D(std::size_t r, std::size_t c) :  row(r), col(c) {}
```

**Fix a spelling error in function name**

I suspect this is a typo. Fix it anyway.

Change

```
  std::size_t numberEatrn() const
```

to

```
  std::size_t numberEaten() const
```

**`getRandom` and `randomChoice()`**

You have a private member variable named `getRandom`, which is initialized as:

```
     Random<double> getRandom{ 0.0, 1.0 };
```

1. I think `getRandom` is a misleading choice of name for a variable. I would expect `getRandom` to be the name of function. I would suggest using a different name, such as `random`.
2. It's used only in `randomChoice()`. If there is ever going to be one instance of `game` in your appliction, which seems like it is, I would suggest putting `random` as a `static` variable in `randomChoice`. It keeps the scope of the variable limited only to where it is needed.

   ```
   bool randomChance(double time)
   {
      static Random<double> random{ 0.0, 1.0 };
      return random() < time;
   }
   ```
3. This is a oh-so-weak suggestion. I would change `Random::operator()()` to `Random::get()`. If you do that, the implementation of `randomChoice` would be:

   ```
   bool randomChance(double time)
   {
      static Random<double> random{ 0.0, 1.0 };
      return random.get() < time;
   }
   ```

   That feels better to me than

   ```
      return random() < time;
   ```

**Replace a `switch` by using an array in `World::draw`**

```
void World::draw(std::ostream& stream) const
{
   static char out[] = {" #$*"};

   clearScreen();

   for (auto&& i : mField)
   {
      for (auto&& j : i)
      {
         stream << out[j];
      }
      stream << '\n';
   }

   std::cout << "Food eaten: " << numEaten << '\n';
}
```

Comment: i thought that the key word `default` is going to initialize members data automatically. what the point of `default` if its act as empty body `{}` only

Answer (score 5):

- This should probably be split into separate files.  Each `class` could have its own file, and `main()` should also have its own.  Even a program of this length is hard to follow well in a single block, and the program may get even larger.
- I would not have the `using` and `namespace` lines right next to each other.  They are not at all related and may mislead someone.
- The `enum` could instead be an `enum class`.  Even if it's not needed right now, it may be useful in case it ever needs to be changed.
- `NonCopyable` can be a `struct`.
- `displayResult()` should be `const`.